# Des conditions procurent des inconvénients mais aussi des avantages

Tags: choix-de-mot, synonymes

Je souhaite trouver la bonne tournure pour cette phrase qui me semble bizarre:

> Ces conditions de vie **procurent** des inconvénients mais aussi des
>   avantages.

Je pourrais aussi utiliser d'autres verbes mais je trouve que toutes ces phrases sont aussi bizarres:

> Ces conditions de vie **confèrent** des inconvénients mais aussi des
>   avantages.
>
> Ces conditions de vie **apportent** des inconvénients mais
>   aussi des avantages.
>
> Ces conditions de vie **donnent** des inconvénients mais aussi des
>   avantages.

Même en acceptant de perdre un peu l'idée de **procurer** et en utilisant simplement le verbe **avoir**, la phrase reste bizarre :

> Ces conditions de vie **auront** des inconvénients mais aussi des
>   avantages.

Comment: "Ces conditions de vie _présentent_ des inconvénients mais aussi des avantages." ? Ou _comportent_ ?

Comment: "Présenter" est en effet le verbe le plus approprié pour ton exemple.

Comment: "procurent" et "présentent" ont un sens éloigné. "procurent" me semble approprié

Comment: Je dirais aussi plutôt : "Ces conditions de vie présentent **(à la fois)** des inconvénients **et** des avantages" ou "Ces conditions de vie présentent **non seulement** des inconvénients, **mais aussi** des avantages", plutôt que le mix des deux que tu as employé dans ton exemple.

Comment: @AodRen Présenter et procurer n'ont en effet pas le même sens. Par exemple un avantage présenter peut être, dans l'example de l'obtention d'une nouvelle carte de fidélité pour un magasin, que la carte de fidélité coûte moins cher à acheter. Un avantage plutôt procuré par cette même carte, serait par exemple qu'elle rend les achats moins chers. Dans le cas de l'OP, les avantages et inconvénients des conditions de vie sont plutôt du premier type.

Comment: Désolé pour la faute présenter -> présenté, mais je ne peux plus corriger mon commentaire.

Comment: Le plus simple: "ont". Sinon, le plus adéquat : "présentent".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ce [N-gram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=conditions+pr%C3%A9sentent%2Cconditions+cr%C3%A9ent%2Cconditions+procurent%2Cconditions+conf%C3%A8rent%2Cconditions+apportent%2Cconditions+donnent%2Cconditions+produisent&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cconditions%20pr%C3%A9sentent%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cconditions%20cr%C3%A9ent%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cconditions%20conf%C3%A8rent%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cconditions%20apportent%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cconditions%20donnent%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cconditions%20produisent%3B%2Cc0) place «donner» en tète de toutes les options que vous proposez en juxtaposition avec «conditions», mais personnellement je trouve «donner» peut-être un peu trop «positif» en parlant des «inconvénients»  et donc je pencherais plutôt vers, comme proposé ailleurs, «présenter» ou même (et voila ce que je propose) soit [«créer» (sens 3)](http://www.linternaute.com/dictionnaire/fr/definition/creer/) ou  [«produire» (sens 4)](http://www.linternaute.com/dictionnaire/fr/definition/produire/)  (que j’ai ajouté au N-gram pour voir), qui vont peut-être mieux tous les trois en parlant des inconvénients **et** des avantages ensembles que "donner" (et qui [«créer» et «produire»] peut-être se trouvent entre "procurer" et "présenter")
(liens à *Linternaute[dot]com* et ses définitions pour «créer» et «produire»)

«Ces conditions de vie créent/produisent  (à la fois) des inconvénients et des avantages».

Answer (score 2):

"Présenter" est le verbe le plus approprié ici, car il s'applique aux deux ; on peut dire à la fois "présenter des inconvénients" et "présenter des avantages".

> Des conditions présentent à la fois des inconvénients mais aussi des avantages.

Comment: Je dirais soit « présentent **à la fois** des inconvénients et des avantages », soit «  présentent des inconvénients **mais aussi** des avantages ». Combiner les deux me semble discutable.